# Do I need an airport transit visa in Seoul

Tags: transit, transit-visas, south-korea, french-citizens

I will be flying Korean Air from Phnom Pehn (Cambodia) to Seoul (South Korea), then Air France to Paris. I will have to go through Korean Immigration.
I am a French citizen.

Do I need an airport transit visa in Seoul. If so, where and when do I get it?
I only have 3 hours to do the transfer, is this enough time?

Answer (score 5):

No visa is required for a French citizen when entering South Korea. French citizens are allowed to stay up to 90 days visa free in South Korea. Also, 3 hours for transit is plenty of time in any major international airport. So, you will be fine.

The Wikipedia reference describes the [visa policy for French citizens.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_French_citizens)

Also, [KLM's TIMATIC Visa Information](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm), used by airlines to confirm passenger requirements, has the  same information that no transit visa is required for French nationals for transiting South Korea.

> National France (FR) 
> Embarkation Cambodia (KH)
>  Transit
>   Korea (Rep.) (KR)  
>      Destination France (FR) 
> ALSO CHECK
>   DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Korea (Rep.) (KR)
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.

Comment: I did an edit; a portion was formatted as a quote from source, although it was not.

Comment: @Dorothy always welcome, you know i always make some mistakes. Appreciated :)